# count of contributors who have entered 4 or more comments - mysql group having

Tags: mysql, count, having

Trying to get a count of contributors who have entered 4 or more comments in reply to another user's original query

parent_id is id of thread starter

so

```
SELECT count(member_id) as response FROM comments
WHERE parent_id=$p_id AND member_id!=$p_id AND category=$category
GROUP BY member_id HAVING count(comment_id)>=4
```

so not only does this return 2 rows it doesn't sum the answer as I'd expect.. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post some sample data.

Comment: Think about it. You're trying to get a nested result.

Comment: Sorry Strawberry - could you elucidate? I have a bodge working by altering the query so I get the number of rows, but would rather underastand what the issue is.